# Переход на страницу вместо показа надписи

Tags: php, html

Есть форма и в ней проверяется заполнение строк, если строки заполнены, то идёт отправка на example@example.com и переход на example.php, но если поля не заполнены, то открывается просто белая страничка с надписью наверху "Необходимо заполнить все поля".

Как сделать, чтобы вместо этой надписи переход шёл на страницу example2.php

```
<?
# получаем данные и отсекаем пробельные символы в начале и конце:
$name    = @trim($_POST['name']);
$contact = @trim($_POST['contact']);
$message = @trim($_POST['message']);
# проверка, переданы ли все данные
if (!$name or !$contact or !$message)
    exit('Необходимо заполнить все поля');
# отправка данных на мыло админу
mail("example@example.com", "Новое объявление для доски объявлений (отправитель: $name)", "Текст объявления: \n $message \n\n Контакты: \n $contact");
header("Location: example.php");
?>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

[Тынц мышкой раз](http://www.phpsql.ru/perenap), [тынц мышой два](http://www.tigir.com/php.htm):

```
if (!$name or !$contact or !$message)
{
  /* перенаправляем на example2.php */; exit();
}
```

Только нужно не забыть заполнить все поля данными, которые ввёл юзер, и пометить некорректные.

Comment: if (! $name or ! $contact or ! $message)
{
  header ("Location: example2.pfp"); exit();
}

Работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: P.S. не буду делать заполнение полей, т.к. реализован JavaScript указывающий на поле (поля), которое не заполнено, а переход на example2.php - это скорее страховка, где JavaScript незаработает